# Git rebase not applying to latest commit of a branch

Tags: git, rebase

I am facing a weird issue during git rebase

I have a branch called Networkconfigs with two commits like C1 & C2, Now I want to rebase with master. conflicts are raising only on top of C1 changes. I am unable to see C2 changes during conflict resolution.

```
command used for rebase at Networkconfigs: git rebase master

branch Networkconfigs
At C1 commit I have a file : Sample.txt
At C2 commit I have replace the Sample.txt with Result.txt
```

during conflict resolution I can see the Sample.txt in Networkconfigs instead of Result.txt. But If I switched Networkconfigs  C2 changes are present(i.e Result.txt existed)

```
git log -5 --graph --oneline NetworkConfigFiles
* df3acf356 (origin/NetworkConfigFiles, NetworkConfigFiles) additional changes
* d7bb7a5dc Incorporate the review comments
* 5243f782f create Network config files
* fb372f921 Incrementing build version to 2.0.2495.0 ***NO_CI***
* 89ce8a232 Incrementing build version to 2.0.2494.0 ***NO_CI***
```

conflicts are raising w.r.t 5243f782f

Comment: can you run `git log -5 --graph --oneline NetworkConfigs`, and paste the output of that command ? (you can edit the messages or names you don't want to show in a public post on StackOverflow as you like, I'm mostly interested in the graph part)

Comment: git log -5 --graph --oneline NetworkConfigFiles
* df3acf356 (origin/NetworkConfigFiles, NetworkConfigFiles) additional changes

* d7bb7a5dc Incorporate the review comments

* 5243f782f create Network config files

* fb372f921 Incrementing build version to 2.0.2495.0 ***NO_CI***

* 89ce8a232 Incrementing build version to 2.0.2494.0 ***NO_CI***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase changes are applied **one at a time** in an orderly fashion so if `C2` is after `C1` in history (actually, if `C1` is listed first in the rebase... given that their order can be shuffled around if using interactive), sure, you won't see `C2`'s changes on `HEAD` until you have gone over applying `C1` changes.

Suppose your branches look like this right now:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- F <- (main)
          ^
           \- G <- H <- I <- (some-branch)
```

Now, suppose that you run this:

```
git checkout some-branch
git rebase main
```

That will mean that `G`, `H` and `I` (or *equivalents*, rather) will be on top of `F`, right? But it's not like magic happens. Git has to apply changes one at a time, so.... if there are conflict when applying `H`, and you take a look at the branch that you are on at the moment, you will find that it looks like this:

```
A <- B <- C <- D <- E <- F <- G' <- (HEAD)
          ^              ^
          |               \- (main)
           \- G <- H <- I <- (some-branch)
```

Notice how on `HEAD`, `I` is not applied yet, so do not expect to see code from that commit where you are standing.

Comment: So I need to rebase C1 first then after C2 is it?

Comment: Let me explain a little bit better in the answer.